# How to write type in D3+Typescript

Tags: typescript, d3.js

```
const ArcChart = ({W, H, data}: IArcChart) => {
    const pieArc:any = d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(W * 2)
    return (
        <g transform={`translate(${W}, ${H})`}>
            {
                data.map((item:IItemProps, index:number) => {
                    return (
                        <Path key={index} fill={item["RGBhexvalue"]} d={pieArc({
                            startAngle: index/data.length * 2 * Math.PI,
                            endAngle: (index + 1)/data.length * 2 * Math.PI
                        })} />
                    )
                })
            }
            </g>
    )
}
```

I'm currently learning D3 and trying to write with typescript.
In this code, I wrote just any, because I really don't know what I should

```
const pieArc:any
```

I don't want to write any.

Comment: Actually you don't need to specify the type at all. Just use: `const pieArc = d3.arc()...`

Comment: hmm Okay! Thank you Have a nice day!